# Odoo 9 Importerror undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_Decode?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I migrated my server from centos 6 to centos 7 and When I tried to run my app It return this error. Help please.

Comment: Please attach the error as text or screenshot that you mention in your question.

Comment: Error solved when upgrading to version 9.4 postgresql